Powerpoint change picture without changing cropping area
My question is similar to this one posted on stackoverflow 9 years ago, viewed 17k times but closed because it should have been posted on superuser based on the comments. I didn't find this question there. Then, here it is.
I've a cropped picture in a PowerPoint slide. I'd like to replace this picture by another one which has same initial dimensions. I want the new picture to be cropped as the previous one. When I click on "Change Picture", instead of getting what I'd expected, the new image is resized to fit in the cropped area.

The only solution I get so far is trying to "uncrop" the cropped image using "Reset Picture & Size", then change the image, and finally crop the new image. However, not only this "uncrops" the image but it also resets the image to its original size which is a problem if the image size was changed.
